# Manage spotify subscription (cancel, upgrade) after user authentication with the spotify api

Tags: api, spotify, spotify-app, spotify-desktop

Is there a way to manage a premium user's subscription after the user is authenticated, as provided by spotify api?

I am able to obtain the user's subscription data by user profile, but cannot cancel or upgrade a premium subscription.

Answer (score 1):

No, changing a user's type of subscription isn't possible using the public Web API.

Basically, if it isn't documented on https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/, it isn't publicly supported. (I work on Spotify's Web API)

Comment: Will it be possible to do it the following way : 1. Authenticate User with spotify api in app 2. Take the user to the cancel subscription page on spotify.com from inapp web view with user's key 3. let the user cancel subscription (or not) from there. (I am trying to create an app to manage user's subscription and this feature would be a great add-on)